# Equivalent PHP language code for C language code using pointers

Tags: php

```
char *pointer = "Hello";
*pointer++;
```

Above code is in C language,
What would be its equivalent PHP code?

Comment: Since PHP doesn't have pointers, there's no equivalent. What does this code *do* that you want to replicate in PHP?

Comment: There are no pointers in PHP.  While they share a somewhat similar syntax, PHP is not C.

Comment: PHP doesnt have pointers, so you wont have any equivalent code for that. Whats the intention behind this code, there might be a function which does that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no pointers in PHP. You can access several chars of a string using the `[]` operator. ([manual](http://www.php.net/manual/de/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.substr)) The following code might do what you need:

```
 $string = "Hello";
 $position = 0;

 $char0 = $string[$position];
 $char1 = $string[++$position];
```

Comment: I think you want a pre-increment operator here, you're just getting char0 twice... :)